# pyspark filter a dataframe using the min value for each id

Tags: dataframe, filter, pyspark, conditional-statements

Given a table like the following:

```
+--+------------------+-----------+
|id|     diagnosis_age|  diagnosis|
+--+------------------+-----------+
| 1|2.1843037179180302| 315.320000|
| 1|  2.80033330216659| 315.320000|
| 1|   2.8222365762732| 315.320000|
| 1|  5.64822705794013| 325.320000|
| 1| 5.686557787521759| 335.320000|
| 2|  5.70572315231258| 315.320000|
| 2| 5.724888517103389| 315.320000|
| 3| 5.744053881894209| 315.320000|
| 3|5.7604813374292005| 315.320000|
| 3|  5.77993740687426| 315.320000|
+--+------------------+-----------+
```

I'm trying to reduce the amount of records per id by only considering the diagnoses with the least diagnosis age per id. In SQL you would join the table to itself, something like:

```
SELECT a.id, a.diagnosis_age, a.diagnosis
    FROM tbl1 a
INNER JOIN
(SELECT id, MIN(diagnosis_age) AS min_diagnosis_age
    FROM tbl1
        GROUP BY id) b
ON b.id = a.id
WHERE b.min_diagnosis_age = a.diagnosis_age
```

If it were an rdd you could do something like:

```
rdd.map(lambda x: (x["id"], [(x["diagnosis_age"], x["diagnosis"])]))\
.reduceByKey(lambda x, y: x + y)\
.map(lambda x: (x[0], [i for i in x[1] if i[0] == min(x[1])[0]]))
```

How would you achieve the same using only spark dataframe operations? If this is possible? Specifically no sql/ rdd operations.

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `window` with `first` function, and then `filter` out all others.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
w=Window().partitionBy("id").orderBy("diagnosis_age")
df.withColumn("least_age", F.first("diagnosis_age").over(w))\
.filter("diagnosis_age=least_age").drop("least_age").show()

+---+------------------+---------+
| id|     diagnosis_age|diagnosis|
+---+------------------+---------+
|  1|2.1843037179180302|   315.32|
|  3| 5.744053881894209|   315.32|
|  2|  5.70572315231258|   315.32|
+---+------------------+---------+
```

You can also do this **without** window function, use `groupBy` `min` and `first`:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df.orderBy("diagnosis_age").groupBy("id")\
.agg(F.min("diagnosis_age").alias("diagnosis_age"), F.first("diagnosis").alias("diagnosis"))\
.show()
+---+------------------+---------+
| id|     diagnosis_age|diagnosis|
+---+------------------+---------+
|  1|2.1843037179180302|   315.32|
|  3| 5.744053881894209|   315.32|
|  2|  5.70572315231258|   315.32|
+---+------------------+---------+
```

**Note** that I am ordering By `diagnosis_age` before the `groupyBy` to handle those cases where your **required diagnosis value does not appear in the first row** of the **group**. **However** , if your data is already ordered by the `diagnosis_age` you can use above code **without** the `orderBy`.

Comment: Hi, trying to run your code and get the following error: AnalysisException: u"Could not resolve window function 'first_value'. Note that, using window functions currently requires a HiveContext;" I assume this would be fixed if I used a hive context, but is there no other workaround?

Comment: @mad-a I have updated solution with a workaround using groupBy.

Comment: version 1.6 with sql context. I ran your first code with hive context and it does work. Your second solution actually doesn't work (the data is much larger than the example table I provided). An id can have more than one diagnosis at the same min diagnosis_age, so taking the first diagnosis excludes any other diagnoses the id might have at the same diagnosis age, if I'm not mistaken? Either way, your first solution works perfectly, just a shame that it can't be replicated without hive context. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

I came across this question and wanted to add a different approach, using a `join` like what you're doing in the SQL example:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

selected = (
    df
    .groupBy('id')
    .agg(F.min('diagnosis_age').alias('diagnosis_age'))
    .select(F.col('id'), F.col('diagnosis_age'))
)

df.join(selected, ['diagnosis_age', 'id'])
```

Where the:

```sql
...
JOIN ON a.id = b.id
WHERE b.min_diagnosis_age = a.diagnosis_age
```

is the same as:

```sql
...
JOIN ON a.id = b.id
    AND a.diagnosis_age = b.min_diagnosis_age
```